# Did the virgin Mary worship Jesus?

Tags: life-of-jesus, virgin-mary, worship

I was reading about Jesus Christ and his miraculous birth, and this question came to my mind:

Would have or did the virgin Mary worship Jesus, after his birth or after his death (according to those who hold that Jesus is God)?

Comment: Why do you think she wouldn't?

Comment: To the closer: Why do you think this is an opinion-based question?

Comment: @Geremia It's unscoped, and not everyone on this site believes that Jesus is to be worshipped.

Comment: If she didn't then, she does now!

Comment: This question will incite opinion, it should be scoped or closed.

Answer (score 3):

She had no doubt He is God; the Archangel Gabriel told her, and, because she knew Holy Scripture, she knew prophecy (e.g., that of Isaias) was being fulfilled through her. After His birth, even the Magi adored Him, so, *a fortiori*, His own mother certainly did.

After His death, St. John provided Holy Communion for her, and thereby she worshiped her Divine Son:

Art. 5 "The Principal Mysteries which Contributed to Mary’s Increase in Grace after the Incarnation", § "Mary, Model of Devotion to the Eucharist" of [*Mother of the Saviour and Our Interior Life*](https://isidore.co/calibre/browse/book/5869) by Fr. Réginald Garrigou-Lagrange, O.P., says:

> It is most becoming to insist here a little on what Holy Mass and Holy Communion, received from the hands of St. John, must have meant for Our Blessed Lady.
>
> Why had Mary been committed to St. John on Calvary rather than to the holy women who were also at the foot of the Cross? The reason was that St. John was a priest and had a treasure which they could not give her, the treasure of the Eucharist.

Answer (score 0):

Mary responds to the news of her special role in the following way:

Luke 1:46-47

> And Mary said: "My soul magnifies the Lord,
>   And my spirit has rejoiced in God **my Savior.**"

Mary knew this meant she was to give birth to her Saviour, the Anointed One, that is, The Son of God. This means she knew her child would be her own personal Saviour before He was born. In fact at the moment of His conception in her. So she would have regarded Him in that light from the beginning, long before He was born.
Before this Gabriel declares to her the following:

> "Do not be afraid, Mary, for you have found favor with God.  And behold, you will conceive in your womb and bring forth a Son, and shall call His name Jesus. He will be great, and will be called the Son of the Highest; and the Lord God will give Him the throne of His father David.And He will reign over the house of Jacob forever, and of His kingdom there will be no end."

So Mary knew exactly who her son would be. His name was to be Yeshua meaning Saviour in Hebrew. This is the name The Father gives to His Son- Yeshua, the Saviour or One who Saves, and His Title is Hamashiach, The Anointed One. Jesus Christ is the Romanized version of that name.
All this Mary would have known from  the start.

Comment: This never seems to answer the question of whether or not Mary worshipped her son.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). For more on what this site is all about, see: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808/20394). Your answer *implies* that Mary would have worshiped Jesus, but doesn't come right out and state it, or provide any support for the belief that she actually *did* worship Jesus. I don't think it's a non-answer, but it's not a particularly *strong* answer.